# How to send an email without the button "send" clicked twice?

Tags: android, email, client, send

I like to send an email using the user app installed on the phone, in this way:
In my app, the user click on a "send" button, that then open the user email client app (Gmail, or Kmail, etc...). And then, to send the email, the user will click on the app "send" button. Here are the "send" two clicks (my app + email client app)!! I don't like.

I want that when the user click my app "send" button and then choose the system email client to be used, the mail is sent without another click to the system email client send button: this should be done automatically!

Is there a way? How?

Comment: I certainly don't want an app using my email to send ads.

Comment: @Geltrude It clearly says in the question you want to send ad email.

Comment: If "to send an email" means "generating spam"--> If every app that sends an email sends spam, also email clients send only spam. I think that email <> spam. Or better spam is usually email, email is not usually spam.

Comment: I was making a joke on your lack of proofreading. Read the title of your question "How to send ad email without the button “send” clicked twice?" You wrote ad instead of an.

Comment: Ahahaha.... Oops... :-)) edit! Thanksss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to send an email using one of the built in clients without the user also clicking send in the email program. If this were possible you could write an app that silently sent emails from users email accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Yup there is a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app/2033124#2033124) that worked fine for me. It uses the JavaMail port

Comment: I know, but for that solution, I need to ask the user for his email accoount password... And I don't want.

Comment: Really ? you want to log in without a username and password ? are you sure you are talking about emails here ?

Comment: I want to send an email using the built in application (as Gmail app) that has the user and password almost saved in it...

Comment: Then the code mentioned above is perfectly okay, go ahead use it.

Comment: @Geltrude, you do not get what they said. If your desired function can be met, then it is a big defect in the system. So you cannot achieve what you want, unless you get the email account password.